# proof that changing basis of bilinear map representation gives $A'=P^tAQ$ (simple question)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B:V XW\rightarrow \mathbb F$ be a bilinear map.

> Let's say $B$ is represented by matrix $A$ using $v_1,...,v_n$ as a basis for $V$ and  $w_1,...,w_m$ as a basis for $W$.
>
> Now, let's take  $v_1',...,v'_n$ as new a basis for $V$ and  $w'_1,...,w'_m$ as a new basis for $W$.
>
> Then there exists matrices $P,Q$ such that $A'=P^tAQ$.

The proof I've seen of the known result starts by stating that:

> $v'_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{ij}v_{i}$
>
> $w'_{l}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}q_{kl}w_{k}
>  $

By computing, it is true that $A'=P^tAQ$.

Why is it so obvious that $P=(p_{ij})$,$Q=(q_{ij})$ are indeed change of basis matrices? (this isn't mentioned in the proof)

Comment: The coefficients $p_{ij}$ exist precisely because $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, and the coefficients $q_{kl}$ exist precisely because $\{v_k\}$ is a basis for $W$; $P$ and $Q$ are therefore change of basis matrices precisely and directly by the very definition of change of basis matrix...

Comment: Sorry, I guess I got a bit confused. I forgot this goes in-between to vectors. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Came to my senses. Thanks anyway.